# Convert LinkedHasSet from one type to another

Tags: kotlin

I have a very simple problem, I need to convert a `LinkedHashSet` that holds one type of object, into another.

So basically what I want to do is something like this(if map could return anything else than TypeB:

```
LinkedHashSet<TypeA> firstSet

LinkedHashSet<TypeB> secondSet = firstSet.map {
   TypeB(firstSet.value1, firstSet.value2)
}
```

This is mostly written to signalize what I want to achieve, of course it doesn't work. Could someone help me write this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` returns a `List`, but you can use [`mapTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-to.html) to insert the resulting elements directly into a collection that you provide as its first argument. This collection is also returned so you can assign it to `secondSet`:

```
val secondSet: LinkedHashSet<TypeB> = firstSet.mapTo(LinkedHashSet<TypeB>()) {
   TypeB(it.value1, it.value2)
}
```

This is more efficient than using `map` because it avoids creating an intermediate `List` to hold the results.